# SSH: how to allow only local port forwarding and forbid remote one (or vise versa) selectively on key basis

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

In `sshd_config`, one can write something like `PermitListen none` and `PermitOpen host:port`, thus allowing local port forwarding while forbidding remote one (or vice versa).

Question: how to do the same in the `authorized_keys` file, in order to achieve the same effect on per-key basis?

Writing

```
restrict,port-forwarding,permitlisten="*:<port>" ssh-ed25519 AAAA...
```

does not prevent the client from making a local port forwarding to whatever host/port combination is currently allowed in the `PermitOpen` section of `sshd_config`, because `port-forwarding` (unlike `AllowTcpForwarding` in `sshd_config`) is not selective and always enables both local and remote forwarding.

Writing any of the following

```
restrict,port-forwarding,permitlisten="*:<port>",permitopen=none ssh-ed25519 AAAA...
restrict,port-forwarding,permitlisten="*:<port>",permitopen=none:none ssh-ed25519 AAAA...
restrict,port-forwarding,permitlisten="*:<port>",permitopen="none" ssh-ed25519 AAAA...
restrict,port-forwarding,permitlisten="*:<port>",permitopen="none:none" ssh-ed25519 AAAA...
```

leads to the connection being silently dropped during authentication, which is a sign that `sshd` considers the `authorized_keys` file syntax invalid.

Answer (score 2):

`_` is an invalid character for hostnames. I'm using the following:

```
restrict,port-forwarding,permitlisten="*:<port>",permitopen="_invalid_hostname_to_restrict_:1" ssh-ed25519 AAAA...
```

I've checked OpenSSH 8.4p1 source codes, but there is no option or keyword to disable only remote port forwarding.

Comment: Neat kludge :) Thanks.